# How do I filter ManyToManyField choices in a Django ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-orm

I want to filter ManyToManyField choices in my ModelForm:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = ['parent_entities']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.root_entity = kwargs.pop('root_entity')
        self.Meta.fields['parent_entities'].queryset = Entity.objects.filter(root_entity=self.root_entity)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I tried a lot of different code I've seen but nothing has worked yet.

I guess my problem is that I can't get this 'parent_entities' field.
With this code, I have the error :

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   # First pop your kwargs that may bother the parent __init__ method
   self.root_entity = kwargs.pop('root_entity')
   # Then, let the ModelForm initialize:
   super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   # Finally, access the fields dict that was created by the super().__init__ call
   self.fields['parent_entities'].queryset = Entity.objects.filter(root_entity=self.root_entity)
```

Comment: I already tried that before but I have this error message:
AttributeError 
'MyForm' object has no attribute 'fields'

Comment: Right, maybe you should call the parent __init__ before accessing MyForm.fields

Comment: If I do so, I have the following error (which makes sense) :
TypeError    
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'root_entity'.  
(actually I didn't see you changed the order of the lines in your initial answer)

Comment: Right, then pop the kwargs before calling __init__ ... Answer updated